# Module not found error : no module named 'Sqlalchemy_access.pyodbc'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

i write a conversion code using vscode in myenv i just had some line for update conversion for which copy the excel data and to append into access file.

i run the code several times in vscode run fine no issue.

but i try to convert it into .exe and run facing error
Module not found error : no module named 'Sqlalchemy_access.pyodbc'

[image]

need a support

find my code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from io import StringIO
from io import BytesIO
import time
import sys
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import sqlalchemy 
import sqlalchemy_access as sq_a
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import shutil
import pyodbc

print("Feeder and BOM data Verification version--py_V.7 interface_GUI/D32023")

os.getcwd()
Chd= os.chdir('D:/NX_BACKWORK/Feeder Setup_PROCESS/#Output/Verified')
Chd = os.getcwd()

df_PM1 = pd.read_excel("BOM_List_OP.xlsx", sheet_name="Part Master")

with pd.ExcelWriter("D:/NX_BACKWORK/Feeder Setup_PROCESS/#Output/Upload/PartMaster.xlsx") as writer:
    df_PM1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="T_PBAR", index=False)

Chd= os.chdir('D:/NX_BACKWORK/Feeder Setup_PROCESS/#Output/Upload')
shutil.copyfile('D:/NX_BACKWORK/Database_File/SMT_Part Master/MODEL.mdb', 'D:/NX_BACKWORK/Feeder Setup_PROCESS/#Output/Upload/MODEL.mdb')
print(pyodbc.drivers())
print('Open Excel....')
df_PM1 = pd.read_excel('PartMaster.xlsx', sheet_name='T_PBAR')
print(df_PM1.head(10))
print('open MS Access....')

cnnstr = (
    r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    r"DBQ=D:\NX_BACKWORK\Feeder Setup_PROCESS\#Output\Upload\MODEL.mdb"
)

cnnurl = f"access+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(cnnstr)}"
acc_engine = create_engine(cnnurl)
print('writing to access')
df_PM1.to_sql("T_PBAR",acc_engine,index=False, if_exists='append')

print('write complete')
```

Comment: Try adding `import sqlalchemy_access as sa_a` near the beginning of your main .py file and then rebuild the .exe to see if that helps.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: `python` wasn't invented do create `exe` and tools like `pyinstaller` may have problem to find all needed Python modules or `C/C++ libraries which it has to add to `exe`. But you can use file `spec` to inform `pyinstaller` what it has to add in exe. You should find more details in `pyinstaller` documentation.

Comment: please find my code

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access/wiki/%5Btip%5D-using-PyInstaller